# modx сделать поле необязательным

Tags: php, cms, modx

в MODX 3.0.2 -> Управление -> Пользователи при создании нового пользователя, поле "Адрес электронной почты" является обязательным, как изменить и сделать его необязательным?

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, что это невозможно, т.к. email -  обязательное поле, если только ковырять ядро.